# Getting degugging error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following script to populate two text fields based on the selection from another field. I have it working in a jsFiddle, but it doesn't work on the actual site. The page in question is:

http://www.ortorderdesk.com/product/prepare-for-your-closing-copy/

And the script is:

```
// JavaScript Document

// Pre populated array of data
var myData1 = new Array();
myData1['DFW Locations...'] = 'Blah';
myData1['Addison'] = '14295 Midway Road, Suite 100';
myData1['Arlington'] = '1241 W. Green Oaks Blvd., Suite 101';
myData1['Colleyville'] = '1210 Hall Johnson Road, Suite 150';
myData1['Fire Wheel'] = '650 Beebalm Lane, Suite 260';
myData1['Flower Mound'] = '3020 Corporate Court, Suite 400';
myData1['Fort Worth'] = '4421 Oak Park Lane, Suite 102';
myData1['Legacy'] = '7500 Dallas Pkwy., Suite 175';
myData1['Mansfield'] = '1405 N. Highway 287, Suite 101';
myData1['McDermott'] = '3915 McDermott Road, Suite 2000';
myData1['Preston Center'] = '8201 Preston Road, Suite 450';
var myData2 = new Array();
myData2['DFW Locations...'] = 'Blah';
myData2['Addison'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['Arlington'] = 'Arlington, TX 76013';
myData2['Colleyville'] = 'Colleyville, TX 76034';
myData2['Fire Wheel'] = 'Garland, TX 75040';
myData2['Flower Mound'] = 'Flower Mound, TX 75028';
myData2['Fort Worth'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['Legacy'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['Mansfield'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['McDermott'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['Preston Center'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';



document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[1].input_1.onchange = updateText;

    function updateText() {
      var obj_sel = document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[1].input_1;
     document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[1].input_19.value = myData1[obj_sel.value];
         var obj_sel = document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[1].input_1;
      document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[1].input_21.value = myData2[obj_sel.value];

}
```

The `[1]` was added because another item, a `<li>`, exists with the class 'cart'.

When I debug and select from the dropdown, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" which I understand means that one of my references is off. However, when I look it over, all of my class, ID and name references appear to match up with the code on the page.

Could someone please look over the page at:
http://www.ortorderdesk.com/product/prepare-for-your-closing-copy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something's adding an *additional* `li` with `class="cart"` to the DOM (there's two total), so you want `document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[2]`.

This code should work regardless of how many elements with `class="cart"` in the DOM:

```
var element = document.querySelector('form.cart');
element.input_1.onchange = updateText;
function updateText() {
    var obj_sel = element.input_1;
    element.input_19.value = myData1[obj_sel.value];
    element.input_21.value = myData2[obj_sel.value];
}
```

Comment: I tried this live on the site (changed all the 1s to 2s) in Chome and it worked. In the future, you can use Ctrl-Shift-J to bring up the console in Chrome and type in the object you want to inspect. Just typing in `document.getElementsByClassName('cart');` shows a three element array you can click through. Most other browsers have something similar.

Comment: Can you post the code you had working? I replaced `[1]` with `[2]` and it's not working.

Comment: Should my references be input_1, input_19, etc. or input_1_1, input_1_19, et.c - one is the ID and the other is the name of the field.

Comment: Every time `document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[1]` appears, change it to `document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[2]`. I'll add some code to the answer.

Comment: I did that, check the site live now... but I also think I accidentally changed the other input reference because I was trying another suggestion.

Comment: I really appreciate the help and I'm sorry to be a pest, but it's not working.

Comment: I just updated the code, try it and see if it works.

Comment: The `location.js` on the site isn't using the most recent code in my answer.

Comment: I think in my original version that you had working, referred to the field by their `ID`s - `input_1_1`, `input_1_19` and `input_1_21` instead of their names like they are now.

Comment: Sorry about that. It should match now.

Comment: This has been such a crazy process for me. I'm more of a designer with a solid HTML and CSS basis and I took on this project without fully looking into how much customization it would take. I appreciate everyone's help. Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to vote up your answer, but when I do, hopefully I can come back and do so.

Comment: If you'd like, you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of my answer under the up/down arrows.

Comment: Done and done. Thank you for streamlining the code with the new variable as well. I realize my original code was in poor form.

Comment: No problem at all, but I just saw another bug: you're defining `myData1['Preston Center']` but the form is using `'Preston Corners'`.